# Count how many times a specific key appears in a multi-dimensional array (the elegant way)

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Suppose the following code:

```
$arr = array(
    0 => array(
        'question' => 'Question 1',
        'choices' => array(
            0 => 'Choice 1',
            1 => 'Choice 2',
            2 => 'Choice 3',
        ),
        'valid' => 'Valid',
        'answer' => 'Answer',
    ),
    1 => array(
        'question' => 'Question 2',
        'choices' => array(
            0 => 'Choice 1',
            1 => 'Choice 2',
            2 => 'Choice 3',
        ),
        'valid' => 'Valid',
    ),
    2 => array(
        'question' => 'Question 3',
        'choices' => array(
            0 => 'Choice 1',
            1 => 'Choice 2',
            2 => 'Choice 3',
        ),
        'valid' => 'Valid',
        'answer' => 'Answer',
    ),
    3 => array(
        'question' => 'Question 4',
        'choices' => array(
            0 => 'Choice 1',
            1 => 'Choice 2',
            2 => 'Choice 3',
        ),
        'valid' => 'Valid',
    ),
);

$answered = 0;
foreach ($arr as $q) {
    if (isset($q['answer'])) {
        $answered++;
    }
}

echo 'Questions: ' . count($arr) . '<br>' . 'Answered questions: ' . $answered;
```

The above code produces the following output:

```
Questions: 4
Answered questions: 2
```

Is there any other (elegant) way to count the answered questions - basically count how many times key `answer` appears in the multi-dimensional array)?

Comment: `count(array_column($arr, 'answer'));`

Comment: @splash58 that was exactly the elegant, one-liner I was looking for... Why don't you post your solution as a separate answer so that I can accept it and give you the credit you deserve?

Comment: I will write late :) - it is not very convenient on the phone. If nobody  do it before :)

Comment: Isolating a single column of data is a mega-duplicate on Stack Overflow.  A new answer is not necessary to resolve this question.  This question, instead, should be closed as a duplicate.